# Shiny app sensitive to minimizing or maximizing the window

Tags: r, window, shiny, minimize

This might be a dumb question, but I could'nt find a solution anywhere. My shiny app is sensitive to minimizing and maximizing of the app-window. Whenever I minimize or maximize the window, the code re-executes. I know there is something I am missing. I tried `isolate`-ing all my reactive functions but I still have this problem. It does'nt happen in the browser window though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using shinydashboard, remember that sidebar menu items are actually hyperlinks.